# Get column value, not ID, from a look up column

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

thank you for reading; my problem is:

I want to retrieve the values of the column "GroupWithPriority". That column is a Look Up from other list.

When I try to get the value, all I get is "GroupWithPriorityId" that gives only a number when I want to get the text... is it possible to do what I want?

I want to get "Group 1" but instead I get

I have already reached a lot and I found nothing :c

I would appreciate your response even if that means that there is no way to do what I want, thank you

My retrievement code looks something like this:

```
this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
                if (response.ok) {  
                    response.json().then((responseJSON) => {  
                        if (responseJSON!=null && responseJSON.value!=null){  
                            console.log(responseJSON.value);    
                        }  
                    }); 
                }  
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your request Url (you may redact out your domain name) -- specifically looking at the syntax of your REST API call.

Comment: Hi Will, here is part of my request: "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items". 'myList' is the main list I'm using. 'Groups' is the second list from where the Look Up is taken

Comment: If you can give me the name of your Lookup column, and name(s) of the column(s) you want to get to get from the Groups list, I can update my example in my answer below for your specific scenario.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, just saw your comment below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access values from the lookup column from a REST query, you need to add the `$expand` parameter to your REST URI to specify the name of the column to expand, then reference the fields in your `$select` prefixed with the Lookup columns name, the `/` character and the name of the field from the reference lookup item you wish to select.  For example:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=Title,ID,LookupField/FieldInTargetList&$expand=LookupField
```

Comment: This is what I came with: ""/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items/?$select=Title, Image, Link, Description, Group, GroupWithPriority/Title&$expand=GroupWithPriority"'

Thank you very very much! It worked :)))